# `docker exec -i db_mysql mysqldump` doesn't produce any backup

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, shell, dump

I have a MySQL Docker container (`db_mysql`) with database `wp_almond`

When I try to dump it with `docker exec -i db_mysql mysqldump` it doesn't work

```bash
$ docker exec -i db_mysql mysqldump -u root -p wp_almond > wp_almond.sql
$ docker exec -i db_mysql ls # Notice that "wp_almond.sql" was not created
bin
boot
dev
docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
entrypoint.sh
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
```

But entering the container and then doing the `mysqldump` inside works

```bash
$ docker exec -it db_mysql sh
$ mysqldump -u root -p wp_almond > wp_almond.sql
$ ls # Here "wp_almond.sql" is present
bin
boot
dev
docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
entrypoint.sh
etc
home
lib
lib64
media
mnt
opt
proc
root
run
sbin
srv
sys
tmp
usr
var
wp_almond.sql
```

I don't know why, I need to do it without entering the container with `sh` for a backup script

Comment: You should be able to run `mysqldump` from the host without entering the container, assuming you've published a port (`docker run -p` option, Compose `ports:` option); you should not need `docker exec` in normal operation.  I'd expect your first invocation to have created the dump file on the host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't get what do ports have to do with this? I only want to do a `mysqldump` then take it out of the container with `docker cp db_mysql:/wp_almond.sql /root/wp_almond.sql`

Comment: And first invocation didn't work, that's the point of the question

Comment: If you started the container with a published MySQL port then you can run `mysqldump` directly from the host without doing anything Docker-specific (though the MySQL command-line tools misinterpret `localhost`, so you do need to make sure you specify `-h 127.0.0.1`).

Comment: If you run the very first command, then run `ls` (not `docker exec` anything) is the file there in the current directory?

Comment: Which will be the syntax for `docker run -p 3306 -h 127.0.0.1 ...`?

Comment: You are right, the file is not being created in the docker contaner, but in my host. If you want to add it as an answer to get the points go for it, I'll accept it as the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

`docker exec -i db_mysql mysqldump -u root -p wp_almond`

then the output is produced to stdout (of your host terminal)

Therefore, when you run

`docker exec -i db_mysql mysqldump -u root -p wp_almond > wp_almond.sql`

It simply redirects the output of your terminal to file on your host itself.

If you want to save it in the container, try this instead

`docker exec -i db_mysql sh -c "mysqldump -u root -p wp_almond > wp_almond.sql"`